# Change layout on Android Activity that uses databinding

Tags: android

I have an android activity that uses databinding extensively. This activity is part of a library and I want to allow users of the library to change the layout.

So I have default_layout.xml
And want the users to be able to use my_layout.xml

The problem is that activity uses databinding and databinding classes are generated. How do I enable people to change the layout without causing casting errors on the databinding classes?

At this point i've read every databinding tutorial there is to find, but somehow this topic doesn't seem to be covered anywhere.

To recap, say that you have activity A

```
class LibraryActivity...
   ActivityMainBinding binding;
```

and want to change the activity in your example

```
class MyCustomizedActivity extends LibraryActivity
    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_customized;
    }
```

How do you prevent an error that looks like this:

```
com.example.example.databinding.MyLayoutBinding cannot be cast to mylibrary.databinding.DefaultLayoutBinding
```